# Validate each item in a json list is contained in another json list

Tags: json, karate

```
* def list1 = [{'a':'value'}, {'b':'value2'}, {'c':'value4'}]
* def list2 = [{'a':'value'}, {'b':'value2'}]
```

I want to validate if all items in list2 exist in list1 using Karate
I am getting boths lists as response from different APIs. Some child values in the given example contain json objects.

I tried to solve this by creating a function and maintaining an array of validation successes(Not optimal). But that too failed as the json were compared as strings and child json objects inside the values mentioned in the example above had different structure(Some contained spaces between parenthesis and newline characters).

```
def result = []
def iterateJson = 
'''
function(item){
if(karate.get('payload').contains(item)
   karate.append(result, true)
else
   karate.append(result, false)
}

'''
karate.foreach(response, iterateJson)
match each result[*] == true
```

Comment: It would be nice of you to show us what you have tried and what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be over-thinking this !

```
* def list1 = [{'a':'value'}, {'b':'value2'}, {'c':'value4'}]
* def list2 = [{'a':'value'}, {'b':'value2'}]
* match list1 contains list2
```

And yes, child objects are handled. Try it and see.

Comment: Ah! In code and in life huh. Thanks @Peter Thomas!

Comment: @professorFreak happens to the best of us ! I love this question, because the reason karate was created was to solve this exact need to do "deep equality" checks, and that's what the `match` keyword is all about

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the answer and for Karate!